# Serving a "Hello World" page using Flask and Apache/mod_wsgi on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

*NOTE: I've found five questions regarding broken "hello world on flask/mod_wsgi" implementations. I have looked through all of them, and can't find the solution to my own broken implementation.  So please don't be too hasty to close this question as a duplicate.*

I'm administering a cloud Ubuntu VM. Currently it's running a LAMP stack. In my webroot I've got a mediawiki and a few HTML files like http://pipad.org/ball/multiball.html -- everything is running okay.

Now I'm trying to have http://pipad.org/foo serve a page dynamically generated by a Python backend, using Flask and Apache/mod_wsgi.

Unfortunately navigating my browser to http://pipad.org/foo results in "URL not found".

Here are my files:

```
pi@PiDroplet:~/web/piFlask$ pwd
/home/pi/web/piFlask

pi@PiDroplet:~/web/piFlask$ ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  628 May 15 02:37 apache.conf
-rwxrwxr-x 1 pi   pi    153 May 15 02:39 piFlask.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 pi   pi    379 May 15 02:38 piFlask.wsgi
drwxrwxr-x 5 pi   pi   4096 May 14 09:06 venv
```

**piFlask.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

# if __name__ == '__main__':
#    app.run()
```

**piFlask.wsgi**

```
# http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/#creating-a-wsgi-file
# http://www.enigmeta.com/2012/08/16/starting-flask/

import os, sys

PROJECT_DIR = '/home/pi/web/piFlask'

activate_this = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'bin', 'activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_DIR)

from piFlask import app as application
```

**apache.conf**

```
pi@PiDroplet:~/web/piFlask$ cat apache.conf 
# Look in http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout & find equiv to /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
# for me (Ubuntu) it's /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
#
# append: 
#    Include /path/to/this/file

# http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/#configuring-apache
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName pipad.org

    WSGIDaemonProcess piFlask user=pi group=pi threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /foo /home/pi/web/piFlask/piFlask.wsgi

    <Directory /home/pi/web/piFlask>
        WSGIProcessGroup piFlask
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And as per the comment in the above config file, ...

```
pi@PiDroplet:~/web/piFlask$ tail -n 2 /etc/apache2/apache2.conf 

Include /home/pi/web/piFlask/apache.conf
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: What about if you use ``<VirtualHost *:80>``?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, thanks, that still doesn't fix it but I'm sure it's one step closer!

Answer (score 3):

You probably have to set `APPLICATION_ROOT` variable to `'/foo'` in [Flask config](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/).

**piFlask.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/foo'

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

Answer (score 2):

This should fix it:

`<VirtualHost *:80>`

Note:

- http://pipad.org/ - right now gives me access to your directory structure one level above piFlask.
- In Flask you have defined only "/" route. So I am not sure how you expect "/foo" to work. Refer [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#routing).

Comment: I think `/` should be okay, as I've used `WSGIScriptAlias /foo /home/pi/web/piFlask/piFlask.wsgi`